# Python, OpenCV: Incompatible library version

Tags: opencv, pycharm, anaconda, libraries, libpng

I'm new here and I want to write programmes with Python and OpenCV.I'm using PyCharm with installed Anaconda and OpenCV but I have the error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kingaszczepanska/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so,
2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/kingaszczepanska/anaconda3/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.0.dylib
Reason: Incompatible library version: libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.dylib requires version 41.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 39.0.0
```

I was looking for the answer but it's still not working. Hope you can help me solving this problem.